# I am having challenges changing Project Build Target on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am running Eclipse on Windows and I am having challenges changing/adding Project Build Target on my project's properties. It is set to Android 4.4W by default, and there are no other options.

It is my understanding that Android Wear supports EditText, which I am trying to add on the app that I am building. Unless, of course, I am wrong about AW's support for EditText.

May I please be assisted with this.

[A screenshot of my project's properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsmQ.png)